# NSMutable Array ,Sprite Kit (EXC_ARITHMETIC) error?

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

Im trying to create a SKlabelNode that will display random text every time the scene is called. I feel like I've done everything right but the game crashes when entering this scene and returns a green error that starts with EXC_ARITHMETIC. Im teaching myself arrays and have no idea what I have done wrong?

.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
@interface EndScene : SKScene{
NSMutableArray *TextArray;
}
@end
```

.m

```
#import "EndScene.h"
#import "MyScene.h"
SKLabelNode *myLabel;

@implementation EndScene
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blackColor];
[self setupLabel];
[self RandomText];
[self loadText];
}
return self;
}

- (void) RandomText
{
int randomNumber = arc4random() % TextArray.count;
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[TextArray   objectAtIndex:randomNumber]];
}

- (void) loadText
{
TextArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[TextArray addObject:@"End Of Game Text"];
[TextArray addObject:@"End Text 2"];
}

-(void) setupLabel{
myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Academy Engraved LET"];
myLabel.fontSize = 44;
myLabel.zPosition = 0;
myLabel.position = CGPointMake(390, 660);
[self addChild:myLabel];
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

SKScene *myScene = [[MyScene alloc]initWithSize:self.size];
SKTransition *doors = [SKTransition crossFadeWithDuration:5];
[self.view presentScene:myScene transition:doors];
}

@end
```

Comment: What line does it crash on ?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the issue is due to your `NSMutableArray` being undefined when executing this line :

```
int randomNumber = arc4random() % TextArray.count;
```

You would likely also get an arithmetic error, if the array count was equal to zero, which would result in a division by zero via the modulo calculation.

The quick fix is to reorder your method calls in the init like this :

```
self setupLabel];
[self loadText]; // now the array is defined
[self RandomText];
```

This is a good example of where you would want to have an understanding of your debugger. You could actually check the values of properties/ivars, like your `TextArray`,  and easily see if something is not defined or not what you expect.

Comment: The reason that's bad is because `% 0` is not allowed. `%` returns the remainder after division, so asking for `% 0` is like asking "what's the remainder after dividing by 0?" which I'm sure you can see is a Bad Thing To Ask...

Comment: Ya, I added that as well. In this case, the array was not even defined based on the code we see above. Not really sure happens in that situation, but I could see something of this nature happening in both cases. (undefined or zero)

Comment: Thank You! So Much! that was to simple... Debugger yes your right.  Could you suggest a specific tutorial or link, book etc. That explains arrays and arc4random in detail.  Id like a better understanding of what I'm doing.

Comment: @prototypical: Instance variables are `nil`-initialized, so `TextArray` was returning `0` for count.

Comment: @anyvn22 - `TextArray` wasn't initialized at time `RandomText` was called. Does it return 0 if it's not initialized ?  The ordering of his calls would solve this issue. However, it would not solve the case of a zero. But as long as `loadText` went first, this code will work.

Comment: @prototypical Yes, `TextArray` being an instance variable rather than a local variable is automatically initialized to `nil` when an instance of `EndScene` is created.